# Is accessing namespace variables as fast as local variables?

Tags: c++, variables, namespaces

If you have one file:

```
//file.h

namespace {
   int x = 5;
}
```

where x is prone to change, and many other files that all use x multiple times, is it slower to call

```
"::x"
```

every single time or is it faster than using a local variable in every file like

```
"int y = ::x"
```

e.g. "::x" doesn't need extra time to be accessed, just like a local?

Comment: Yes, it is equally as fast. The variable's scope is not reflected in the generated code. This is all for human readability and code maintenance purposes.

Comment: Your compiler's generated assembly would clear it up pretty quickly.

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that one is faster than the other, but why don't you just measure the difference? But in any case, you should know that using an anonymous namespace in a header file is a very bad idea and will very likely cause violations of the ODR.

Comment: The namespace is entirely a language maintenance feature. It is not reflected at all in the generated code (save possible in the symbol name mangling).

Comment: Attempting to measure the difference would be very misleading. You'd very likely see a minor difference, but that would just be noise. You shouldn't read anything into it. The "always measure" mantra is great, but only when you understand what you are actually measuring. Also, it would be *extremely* difficult to craft a benchmark that could actually measure this. I'd bet dollars to donuts if anyone here tried to measure it, they'd get a misleading result.